# NoMethodError - undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass with Sinatra app when deployed on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, datamapper

I am stuck with this problem. I have the following DataMapper model in my Sinatra app;

```
class Word
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial, :key => true
  property :word, String
end
```

The following is another snippet of my code;

```
get '/kamus/:alph' do
  @alph = %w{A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z}

  firstword = Word.first(:word.like=>"#{params[:alph]}%")
  lower = firstword.id
  lastword = Word.last(:word.like=>"#{params[:alph]}%")
  upper = lastword.id
  @words = Word.all(:id=>(lower..(lower+(upper-lower)%1000)))
  erb :kamus
end
```

The problem I'm encountering is; on local development environment, everything works fine. But when I deploy on Sinatra, I'm getting the infamous "Internal Server Error". In my command line I typed;

```
heroku logs
```

and I've found out that the problem has to do with the id property according to the following;

```
NoMethodError - undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass:
```

I am aware that I'm using different Databases (in development; SQLite3 and in production; PostgreSQL). I am puzzled as to why Heroku is not recognizing the variable firstword and lastword as type Word. I'm quite sure that the problem has to do with that, because when I substitute the variables lower and upper with integers manually read from my SQL table, the app works fine. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Firstly, do the words exist in the database on heroku? Secondly, are you doing a case-insensitive LIKE query or a case-sensitive one? The latter one may return nothing. Thirdly, even if there aren't any records, your app should not crash. It should just return an empty collection to the view so that it can say "No records found"

Comment: thanks for answering. to your questions; yes Words exist in the database on heroku. I think your second respond might be a clue of my problem because I didn't even think of the query being case sensitive or case insensitive. I think if there are no records found, there'll be no method from class Word to be accessed in the first place. I'll check on this immediately.

Comment: You were right! Apparently the a datamapper query to SQLite is not case sensitive and a datamapper query to Postgres IS. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. I'll turn my comment into an answer and you accept it. This way, my e-penis enlarges while helping you, :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do the words exist in the database on heroku?

Secondly, are you doing a case-insensitive LIKE query or a case-sensitive one? The latter one may return nothing.

Thirdly, even if there aren't any records, your app should not crash. It should just return an empty collection to the view so that it can say "No records found".

Comment: i felt a new emotion. i'm feeling dirty mixed with thankfulness. :D